# I have a List of Enums that needs to be Passed to a database, I'm using Spring Data JDBC, How to do that?

Tags: json, database, spring-boot, spring-data, spring-data-jdbc

I have a Movie class which has this fields :

```
@Table(value = "MOVIES")
public record Movie(
        @Id
        long id,
        @NotBlank
        String title,
        String director,
        @NotNull
            @Column("MYEAR")
        Long year,
        List<Genre> genre
) {}
```

It consist of Genre, where each movie can contain more than one genre. So I used a List for it.

And the Genre is a Enum, It's look like

```
public enum Genre {
    BIOGRAPHY,
    DRAMA,
    HISTORY,
    FANTASY,
    ACTION,
    ADVENTURE,
    COMEDY,
    ROMANCE,
    CRIME,
    HORROR,
    ANIMATION,
    MYSTERY,
    SCIFI,
    THRILLER,
    DOCUMENTARY,
    FAMILY,
    MUSIC,
    SPORT,
    WAR;
}
```

Since, I'm using Spring Boot

I have a RestController, Repository

Controller :

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/movies")
public class MovieCollectionController {
    private final MovieRepository repository;

    public MovieCollectionController(MovieRepository repository) {
        this.repository = repository;
    }

    @GetMapping
    public List<Movie> findAll(){
        List<Movie> all = repository.findAll();
        System.out.println(all);

        return repository.findAll();
    }

    @PostMapping
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.CREATED)
    public void create(@Valid @RequestBody Movie movie){
        repository.save(movie);
    }
}
```

and Since I'm using Spring data jdbc, I created an Interface which extends ListCrudRepository<T, ID>

Repository Interface :

```
public interface MovieRepository extends ListCrudRepository<Movie, Long> {}
```

Due to Spring Data jdbc, we don't need to write any queries for Accessing the data from the Database.

I'm Using an Embedded H2 database, where I connected Successfully and Created the Table with schema
Table Schema :

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS movies(
    id INTEGER AUTO_INCREMENT,
    title VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    director VARCHAR(255),
    myear INTEGER NOT NULL,
    genre VARCHAR(255),
    primary key(id)
);

INSERT into movies (title, director, myear, genre)
VALUES (
    'RRR',
    'Rajamouli',
    2022,
    'ACTION, DRAMA'
);

INSERT INTO movies (title, director, myear, genre)
VALUES (
    'The Shawshank Redemption',
    'Frank Darabont',
    1994,
    'DRAMA,CRIME'
);
```

When the Application Starts this schema will be automatically Runs due to properties I Set in application.properties file

Have a look :

```
spring.datasource.generate-unique-name=false
spring.datasource.name=movies
spring.sql.init.mode=always
```

When I started/Run this SpringBoot Application, the Schema is executed and Successfully Created the table and Inserted the data. Where Genre is Inserted as

```
|GENRE|
|ACTION, DRAMA|
|DRAMA, CRIME|
```

When I did a getMapping from the Browser, I got the result as

```
[
{"id":1,"title":"RRR","director":"Rajamouli","year":2022,"genre":["ACTION","DRAMA"]},{"id":2,"title":"The Shawshank Redemption","director":"Frank Darabont","year":1994,"genre":["DRAMA","CRIME"]}
]
```

Which feels ok!.

when I try to Insert a Movie into the database from a POST Mapping

application/json content and with body :

```
  {
    "title": "KGF",
    "director": "Prashanth Neel",
    "year": 2022,
    "genre": [
      "ACTION",
      "DRAMA"
    ]
  }
```

The data inserts into the database as like this :

```
|GENRE|
|[ACTION, DRAMA]|
```

So, when I again try a get request from the database it throws an error :

See the Trace

```
2023-06-27T21:25:58.791+05:30 ERROR 1578 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed: org.springframework.core.convert.ConversionFailedException: Failed to convert from type [java.lang.String] to type [com.dharmateja.moviescollectorspringData.model.Genre] for value [[ACTION]] with root cause

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No enum constant com.dharmateja.moviescollectorspringData.model.Genre.[ACTION
    at java.base/java.lang.Enum.valueOf(Enum.java:273) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.core.convert.support.StringToEnumConverterFactory$StringToEnum.convert(StringToEnumConverterFactory.java:54) ~[spring-core-6.0.10.jar:6.0.10]
    at org.springframework.core.convert.support.StringToEnumConverterFactory$StringToEnum.convert(StringToEnumConverterFactory.java:39) ~[spring-core-6.0.10.jar:6.0.10]
    at org.springframework.core.convert.support.GenericConversionService$ConverterFactoryAdapter.convert(GenericConversionService.java:437) ~[spring-core-6.0.10.jar:6.0.10]
    at org.springframework.core.convert.support.ConversionUtils.invokeConverter(ConversionUtils.java:41) ~[spring-core-6.0.10.jar:6.0.10]
    at org.springframework.core.convert.support.GenericConversionService.convert(GenericConversionService.java:192) ~[spring-core-6.0.10.jar:6.0.10]
    at org.springframework.core.convert.support.StringToCollectionConverter.convert(StringToCollectionConverter.java:80) ~[spring-core-6.0.10.jar:6.0.10]
    at org.springframework.core.convert.support.ConversionUtils.invokeConverter(ConversionUtils.java:41) ~[spring-core-6.0.10.jar:6.0.10]
    at org.springframework.core.convert.support.GenericConversionService.convert(GenericConversionService.java:192) ~[spring-core-6.0.10.jar:6.0.10]
    at org.springframework.data.relational.core.conversion.BasicRelationalConverter.getPotentiallyConvertedSimpleRead(BasicRelationalConverter.java:264) ~[spring-data-relational-3.1.1.jar:3.1.1]
    at org.springframework.data.relational.core.conversion.BasicRelationalConverter.readValue(BasicRelationalConverter.java:155) ~[spring-data-relational-3.1.1.jar:3.1.1]
    at org.springframework.data.jdbc.core.convert.BasicJdbcConverter.readValue(BasicJdbcConverter.java:218) ~[spring-data-jdbc-3.1.1.jar:3.1.1]
    at org.springframework.data.jdbc.core.convert.BasicJdbcConverter$ReadingContext.readFrom(BasicJdbcConverter.java:480) ~[spring-data-jdbc-3.1.1.jar:3.1.1]
    at org.springframework.data.jdbc.core.convert.BasicJdbcConverter$ReadingContext.readOrLoadProperty(BasicJdbcConverter.java:449) ~[spring-data-jdbc-3.1.1.jar:3.1.1]
    at org.springframework.data.jdbc.core.convert.BasicJdbcConverter$ReadingContext$ResultSetParameterValueProvider.getParameterValue(BasicJdbcConverter.java:587) ~[spring-data-jdbc-3.1.1.jar:3.1.1]
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.model.SpELExpressionParameterValueProvider.getParameterValue(SpELExpressionParameterValueProvider.java:49) ~[spring-data-commons-3.1.1.jar:3.1.1]
    at org.springframework.data.relational.core.conversion.BasicRelationalConverter$ConvertingParameterValueProvider.getParameterValue(BasicRelationalConverter.java:298) ~[spring-data-relational-3.1.1.jar:3.1.1]
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.model.ClassGeneratingEntityInstantiator.extractInvocationArguments(ClassGeneratingEntityInstantiator.java:301) ~[spring-data-commons-3.1.1.jar:3.1.1]
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.model.ClassGeneratingEntityInstantiator$EntityInstantiatorAdapter.createInstance(ClassGeneratingEntityInstantiator.java:273) ~[spring-data-commons-3.1.1.jar:3.1.1]
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.model.ClassGeneratingEntityInstantiator.createInstance(ClassGeneratingEntityInstantiator.java:98) ~[spring-data-commons-3.1.1.jar:3.1.1]
    at org.springframework.data.relational.core.conversion.BasicRelationalConverter.createInstance(BasicRelationalConverter.java:136) ~[spring-data-relational-3.1.1.jar:3.1.1]
    at org.springframework.data.jdbc.core.convert.BasicJdbcConverter$ReadingContext.createInstanceInternal(BasicJdbcConverter.java:556) ~[spring-data-jdbc-3.1.1.jar:3.1.1]
    at org.springframework.data.jdbc.core.convert.BasicJdbcConverter$ReadingContext.mapRow(BasicJdbcConverter.java:406) ~[spring-data-jdbc-3.1.1.jar:3.1.1]
    at org.springframework.data.jdbc.core.convert.BasicJdbcConverter.mapRow(BasicJdbcConverter.java:304) ~[spring-data-jdbc-3.1.1.jar:3.1.1]
    at org.springframework.data.jdbc.core.convert.EntityRowMapper.mapRow(EntityRowMapper.java:63) ~[spring-data-jdbc-3.1.1.jar:3.1.1]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.RowMapperResultSetExtractor.extractData(RowMapperResultSetExtractor.java:94) ~[spring-jdbc-6.0.10.jar:6.0.10]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.RowMapperResultSetExtractor.extractData(RowMapperResultSetExtractor.java:61) ~[spring-jdbc-6.0.10.jar:6.0.10]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate$1.doInPreparedStatement(JdbcTemplate.java:723) ~[spring-jdbc-6.0.10.jar:6.0.10]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:651) ~[spring-jdbc-6.0.10.jar:6.0.10]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:713) ~[spring-jdbc-6.0.10.jar:6.0.10]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:738) ~[spring-jdbc-6.0.10.jar:6.0.10]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:794) ~[spring-jdbc-6.0.10.jar:6.0.10]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.namedparam.NamedParameterJdbcTemplate.query(NamedParameterJdbcTemplate.java:209) ~[spring-jdbc-6.0.10.jar:6.0.10]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.namedparam.NamedParameterJdbcTemplate.query(NamedParameterJdbcTemplate.java:221) ~[spring-jdbc-6.0.10.jar:6.0.10]
    at org.springframework.data.jdbc.core.convert.DefaultDataAccessStrategy.findAll(DefaultDataAccessStrategy.java:275) ~[spring-data-jdbc-3.1.1.jar:3.1.1]
    at org.springframework.data.jdbc.core.JdbcAggregateTemplate.findAll(JdbcAggregateTemplate.java:341) ~[spring-data-jdbc-3.1.1.jar:3.1.1]
    at org.springframework.data.jdbc.repository.support.SimpleJdbcRepository.findAll(SimpleJdbcRepository.java:89) ~[spring-data-jdbc-3.1.1.jar:3.1.1]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:104) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:577) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryMethodInvoker$RepositoryFragmentMethodInvoker.lambda$new$0(RepositoryMethodInvoker.java:288) ~[spring-data-commons-3.1.1.jar:3.1.1]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryMethodInvoker.doInvoke(RepositoryMethodInvoker.java:136) ~[spring-data-commons-3.1.1.jar:3.1.1]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryMethodInvoker.invoke(RepositoryMethodInvoker.java:120) ~[spring-data-commons-3.1.1.jar:3.1.1]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryComposition$RepositoryFragments.invoke(RepositoryComposition.java:516) ~[spring-data-commons-3.1.1.jar:3.1.1]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryComposition.invoke(RepositoryComposition.java:285) ~[spring-data-commons-3.1.1.jar:3.1.1]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$ImplementationMethodExecutionInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:628) ~[spring-data-commons-3.1.1.jar:3.1.1]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184) ~[spring-aop-6.0.10.jar:6.0.10]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:168) ~[spring-data-commons-3.1.1.jar:3.1.1]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:143) ~[spring-data-commons-3.1.1.jar:3.1.1]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184) ~[spring-aop-6.0.10.jar:6.0.10]
    at org.springframework.data.projection.DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.java:72) ~[spring-data-commons-3.1.1.jar:3.1.1]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184) ~[spring-aop-6.0.10.jar:6.0.10]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:123) ~[spring-tx-6.0.10.jar:6.0.10]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:391) ~[spring-tx-6.0.10.jar:6.0.10]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:119) ~[spring-tx-6.0.10.jar:6.0.10]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184) ~[spring-aop-6.0.10.jar:6.0.10]
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:137) ~[spring-tx-6.0.10.jar:6.0.10]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184) ~[spring-aop-6.0.10.jar:6.0.10]
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:97) ~[spring-aop-6.0.10.jar:6.0.10]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184) ~[spring-aop-6.0.10.jar:6.0.10]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:244) ~[spring-aop-6.0.10.jar:6.0.10]
    at jdk.proxy2/jdk.proxy2.$Proxy80.findAll(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at com.dharmateja.moviescollectorspringData.controller.MovieCollectionController.findAll(MovieCollectionController.java:30) ~[classes/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:104) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:577) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:207) ~[spring-web-6.0.10.jar:6.0.10]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:152) ~[spring-web-6.0.10.jar:6.0.10]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:118) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.10.jar:6.0.10]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:884) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.10.jar:6.0.10]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:797) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.10.jar:6.0.10]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.10.jar:6.0.10]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1081) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.10.jar:6.0.10]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:974) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.10.jar:6.0.10]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1011) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.10.jar:6.0.10]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:903) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.10.jar:6.0.10]
    at jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:564) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.10.jar:6.0]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:885) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.10.jar:6.0.10]
    at jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:658) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.10.jar:6.0]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:205) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.10.jar:10.1.10]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.10.jar:10.1.10]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:51) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-10.1.10.jar:10.1.10]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.10.jar:10.1.10]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.10.jar:10.1.10]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) ~[spring-web-6.0.10.jar:6.0.10]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.0.10.jar:6.0.10]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.10.jar:10.1.10]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.10.jar:10.1.10]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-6.0.10.jar:6.0.10]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.0.10.jar:6.0.10]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.10.jar:10.1.10]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.10.jar:10.1.10]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) ~[spring-web-6.0.10.jar:6.0.10]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.0.10.jar:6.0.10]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.10.jar:10.1.10]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.10.jar:10.1.10]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.10.jar:10.1.10]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:90) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.10.jar:10.1.10]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:482) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.10.jar:10.1.10]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:115) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.10.jar:10.1.10]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:93) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.10.jar:10.1.10]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.10.jar:10.1.10]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:341) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.10.jar:10.1.10]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:391) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.10.jar:10.1.10]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:63) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.10.jar:10.1.10]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:894) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.10.jar:10.1.10]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1741) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.10.jar:10.1.10]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:52) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.10.jar:10.1.10]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.10.jar:10.1.10]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.10.jar:10.1.10]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.10.jar:10.1.10]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833) ~[na:na]
```

Due to the genre data in the database is `[ACTION, DRAMA]`

The Spring Data cannot convert into enum type and create Movie object may be.

Feel free to ask anymore data.

I tried different payloads while making a POST Request but non of them seems working

Like one here :

```
{
  "title": "The Shawshank Redemption",
  "director": "Frank Darabont",
  "year": 1994,
  "genre": [
    {
      "name": "DRAMA"
    },
    {
      "name": "CRIME"
    }
  ]
}
```

Two :

```
{
  "title": "The Shawshank Redemption",
  "director": "Frank Darabont",
  "year": 1994,
  "genre": "DRAMA, ACTION"
}
```

and few other types, but nothing working
If changed the payload, IntelliJ is throwing me :

```
Resolved [org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: JSON parse error: Cannot deserialize value of type `com.dharmateja.moviescollectorspringData.model.Genre` from Object value (token `JsonToken.START_OBJECT`)]
```

or

```
Resolved [org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: JSON parse error: Cannot deserialize value of type `java.util.ArrayList<com.dharmateja.moviescollectorspringData.model.Genre>` from Object value (token `JsonToken.START_OBJECT`)]
```

So, Please help me